# ArrayList From cache

Tags: java, arraylist

I am retrieving values from cache and it retrieves an array of values.But I need to pick a particular value from the arrayList. How can I do it?

This is the output from the cache.

```
data =Fruits 
        Apple - 50
        Banana - 20
        Orange - 60
```

I need to access Apple. I can get to Fruits using `data.get(0)`. But I dont know how to access Apple -50. Can any one please help?

Comment: what is the cache mapping to ?

Comment: ArrayList contains an ordered list of elements. Are you talking about a map perhaps?

Comment: I am using Websphere Extreme scale as cache and storing frequently used data as tables. I am querying the cache for eg: In this case, String query = 'select t from fruittable where price>15'; When I execute I get an array of the results which I gave in my question. Now I need to access a particular value from the array results.

Comment: Please ask your vendor, I think he provides commercial support.